# Maintain a client-side http cache with aiohttp

Tags: python-3.x, caching, python-requests, aiohttp

I have a synchronous app using [cache-control](https://pypi.org/project/CacheControl/) + [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) which works well with a local filesystem cache. I'm looking to migrate this to an async project using [aiohttp-client](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client.html) however, it looks like there aren't any client-side caching libraries that work with it?

Are there any async HTTP clients in Python that I can use a local cache with?

Comment: I'm looking for such library too. What if we cooperate and write our own library?

Comment: I've started it here - https://github.com/MasterSergius/acachecontrol
Any help is welcome

Answer (score 2):

The [`aiohttp-client-cache`](https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp-client-cache/) library works with `aiohttp-client` and can be used to [store cache on a local filesystem](https://aiohttp-client-cache.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/aiohttp_client_cache.backends.filesystem.html#aiohttp_client_cache.backends.filesystem.FileBackend).