# Is there some caching lib for aiohttp like CacheControl for requests? [Python]

Tags: python, asynchronous, cache-control

I used [CacheControl](https://pypi.org/project/CacheControl/) together with python requests library. It automatically parses cache-control header and use it to configure cache. Now I need to rewrite whole module to make it asynchronous, but can't find anything similar for aiohttp.
I've found this one [aiohttp-cache](https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp-cache/), but it serves for a different purposes. Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Duplicate of (unanswered) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64681401/maintain-a-client-side-http-cache-with-aiohttp

Comment: Eh, unanswered... Maybe, that's why I didn't find it )

Comment: Ok, stackoverflow... I've started my own library https://github.com/MasterSergius/acachecontrol
Contributors are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no answers and no libraries found, I can introduce my own library - https://github.com/MasterSergius/acachecontrol
v 0.3.0 available at the moment, try it if you need.